# Getting weird behavior from phantom js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, closures

I am using phantomjs to execute below code.
I am unable to figure out whats wrong here.

```
function process(arg1, arg2) {

    var webpage = require('webpage').create();

    webpage.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        // something
    };

    webpage.onError = function(msg, trace) {

        // something
    };

    webpage.open(entityResolvedFilePath, function(status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {

            abort(ErrorCode['HTML_LOAD_FAILURE']);

        } else {

            injectScriptsToWebpage(webpage);

            if (inputParams['myExpression']) {

                var outerWebPagescope=webpage;
                window.wepPage=webpage;
                webpage.evaluate(function() {

                    if (hasRequiredNoides(document)) {
                      //do something
                    }
                    else {

                        //outerWebPagescope.onCallback(); this also doesn't works
                        wepPage.onCallback();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                webpage.onCallback();
            }
        }
    });

    webpage.onCallback = function() {

        webpage.evaluate(function(inputParams) {
            //do something
        });

    };
}
```

when i am calling webpage.evaluate inside webpage.open it create a new function scope so i am tring to access outer variable by create a reference **outerWebPagescope** , but i am unable to access it.
As far as i understand closures this should work.

Can anyone explain me this.
Somehow i am unable to debug callback codes by using phantomjs, that code never hit my debugger in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In PhantomJS function inside of `page.evaluate` is not just a closure, it exists insode of another context (that of a webpage) in which all outer variables and function do not exist, but a web page's DOM is available instead.

If I understand your intention, you'd like to interact with outer context from the context of a web page. There are two ways for that:

• You can `return` data from `page.evaluate`, but it must be a simple serializable object or array.

• You can call a special utility function `window.callPhantom` injected into a webpage spcifically for that kind of interaction:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom({ hello: 'world' });
    }
});

page.onCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('CALLBACK: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  // Prints 'CALLBACK: { "hello": "world" }'
};
```

Docs: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html

Comment: Thanks for response, I always get window.callPhantom as undefined.